# Unable to execute the query

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I entered the code like shown below, I get back this error:

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Code:

```
SELECT 
    E_ID, E_NAME, PROJECT, MANAGER
FROM 
    EMPLOYEE_PROJECT 
INNER JOIN 
    EMP_MASTER ON (EMPID = E_ID AND LOCATION = 'MUMBAI' AND 
                   E_ID NOT IN (SELECT * FROM SALARY_ADVANCE))
```

Comment: @Pala which RDBMS you are using..

Comment: replace * with only eid feild like below...

Answer (score 9):

Problem is here

```
 E_ID NOT IN (SELECT * FROM SALARY_ADVANCE))
```

You have to mention one column instead of all

Answer (score 7):

The issue in this line:

```
E_ID NOT IN (SELECT * FROM SALARY_ADVANCE)
```

You should mention what field you check in this SELECT. Otherwise you get a table set not a set of values.

```
E_ID NOT IN (SELECT FIELD_NAME FROM SALARY_ADVANCE)
```

Answer (score 3):

`NOT IN` is a bit tricky, because it returns zero rows if a `NULL` is returned from the sub-query. Perhaps not what's expected in many cases... Add a `IS NOT NULL` to the sub-query to avoid this.

```
SELECT E_ID, 
       E_NAME, 
       PROJECT, 
       MANAGER
  FROM EMPLOYEE_PROJECT INNER JOIN EMP_MASTER ON 
         EMPID = E_ID AND 
         LOCATION = 'MUMBAI' AND 
         E_ID NOT IN (SELECT E_ID 
                        FROM SALARY_ADVANCE
                      WHERE E_ID IS NOT NULL)
```

You can also re-write to a `NOT EXISTS`, which is null-safe!

```
SELECT E_ID, 
       E_NAME, 
       PROJECT, 
       MANAGER
  FROM EMPLOYEE_PROJECT INNER JOIN EMP_MASTER ON (
         EMPID = E_ID AND 
         LOCATION = 'MUMBAI' AND 
         NOT EXISTS (SELECT E_ID 
                     FROM SALARY_ADVANCE as SA
                     WHERE SA.E_ID = EMP*table*.E_ID))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT E_ID, 
       E_NAME, 
       PROJECT, 
       MANAGER
  FROM EMPLOYEE_PROJECT INNER JOIN EMP_MASTER ON 
         EMPID = E_ID AND 
         LOCATION = 'MUMBAI' AND 
         E_ID NOT IN (SELECT E_ID 
                        FROM SALARY_ADVANCE)
```